# where I can get some tutorials on Java FitNesse and Slim?

Tags: java, testing, tdd, fitnesse

I am studying TDD using [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) and I am looking some tutorials and examples. I would like to know where to find a good material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some material on slideshare (a youtube alike, but for sharing presentations) :
http://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?searchfrom=header&q=fitnesse

Answer (score 4):

http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/FitNesse.Tutorials have a lot of examples 
(Both Java and C#)

Comment: I liked this tutorial! Very Good!! =D

Answer (score 2):

Unclebob put good videos about the fitnesse in the fitnesse site (http://fitnesse.org/FrontPage.VideoTutorials). Check out.

Comment: Unfortunately the last few videos are private and not viewable.