# Getting started testing .NET with FitNesse

Tags: c#, .net, fitnesse

I am quite new to fitnesse, I really like the ideas. But how do you do it in real life?
I have a solution that contains several dll projects in visual studio.
The projects use each other.
It's basically WPF projects so it should be relatively easy to make Fitnesse a new view that uses the viewmodels.

I think the solution here is to make a project for fitnesse, `a.proj`. that project will link to other assemblies that we make. lets say that `b` is where our business logic is and `c`, contains some lower level logic. In `b` I have my business class.

```
namespace b {   
   public class SomeBusinesslogic {
       public C:SomeValue something;
       public bool DoSomething(C:SomeOtherValue value1,C:Somevalue value2){
           ... somelogic ....
       }
   }
}
namespace c {
  public class SomeValue{
    public int a;
    public int b;
  }
  public class SomeOtherValue{
    public float c;
    public string textd;
  }
}
```

in my fitnesse wiki page how would I write the paths to include a.dll that is my fitness wrapping. and b.dll that is under test. And the c.dll that is also called through b.dll.

```
!path ..\xxx\bin\c.dll
!path ..\xxx\bin\b.dll
!path ..\xxx\bin\a.dll
```

or is there any smarter way of doing this?
thanks

Comment: You would be better off starting with a some beginner tutorial on FitNesse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632159/where-i-can-get-some-tutorials-on-java-fitnesse-and-slim

Comment: I should remember better what dll's are not static libraris...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you get started http://www.asoftwarecraft.com/2011/07/starting-fitnesse-project-with-fitsharp.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one path variable with comma-separated list.

Also there are different behaviours. FitSharp runner requires the list of the namespaces or classes which are defined in the configuration (see the project above). NetRunner plugin requires the dlls list in the path only. Then it will find all classes inherited from the BaseTestContainer class and add them to the functions containers list. Then it will union all these function to the one list and will use this list for test execution.

And important note for the configuration file: for the fitSharp you have to show the configuration file directly. For the NetRunner the configuration file will be used from the first library availble. So, for example you have this path variable:
!path a.dll, b.dll, c.dll, d.dll

b.dll and c.dll contains configuration, e.g. there is two existing files: b.dll.config and c.dll.config. And there are any configuration for the a.dll and d.dll. Then the b.dll.config will be used for the test domain.